# Missing $ inserted: Cannot find my error

Tags: luatex, missing

I am getting the following error message:

> Missing $ inserted. ...bord, le premier phaseur U1 est égal à Ue^

… but I cannot find my mistake. I would therefore appreciate your help !

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage[head=1pt,margin=0.3in,bottom=0.3in,includeheadfoot=    False]{geometry}%
\usepackage{hyperref}%
\usepackage{bm}
%
\usepackage{needspace}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{graphicx, array}%
\usepackage{textalpha} % <--- Greek letters in text
%
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amssymb} % <----  for real number symbol (R)
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}




\begin{document}%


 Ue^{(j$\alpha$ )}. Je laisse volontairement l'angle $\alpha$      

\end{document}
```

EDIT:

I have this:

```
Ue^(jα)
```

And I want to automatically transcribe it to Latex code... so I replace all greec letters with their math mode equivalent (i.e. `$\alpha$`)

Comment: `Ue^(j$\alpha$ )` is not allowed, try `$Ue^{(j\alpha )}$` instead. There is some room for further improvement.

Comment: `\dots` should be in math mode, isn't it?

Comment: @marmot It's actually like that in my text ? Ue^(j$\alpha$ )

Comment: @manooooh I tried to add `$` but it does not change it.

Comment: Then load `amsmath` and do `$\text{Ue}^{(\text{j}\alpha )}$`.

Comment: @marmot I reduced my question to the main issue. I tried:  `Ue^{(j$\alpha$ )} ` but it does not help.

Comment: Yes, because you need to switch to math mode to use `^`.

Comment: @marmot I see. Would there be a method to keep text mode and replace the `^`with something else ?

Comment: `\textsuperscript`: Ue\textsuperscript{(j$\alpha$)} should work.

Comment: @marmot Great. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @marmot Can you add it as answer ? Then I can accept it.

Comment: do not use `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}%` with luatex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely this is a duplicate of something but since you explicitly asked to write an answer, here it is. `^` is not allowed in text mode, but `\textsuperscript` is. So you could (with your preamble) either do

```
 Ue\textsuperscript{(j$\alpha$ )}. Je laisse volontairement l'angle $\alpha$
```

[image]

or, since you load `textgreek`, avoid math mode altogether

```
Ue\textsuperscript{(j\textalpha )}. Je laisse volontairement l'angle \textalpha
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer ! Thank you for also mentioning textgreek.